# XCode UI Testing: Can I use UI Testing scripts to access the documents directory of the target app?

Tags: xcode, swift3, xctest

I am testing an iOS app using XCTest Framework. I have to access/read projects from the Documents directory of the target app. Since XC Framework installs itself as a separate app on the simulator, I cannot access the directory as the app runs in sandboxed environment. Is there any way to access the directory apart from uploading the files on Cloud storage or using shared storage by making a common App Group (both of these options do not look feasible as the project size is too large and the Common App Group method seems to be complicated)?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: yeah, the point is to have an isolated case to run everything.